# Can't create MongoClient.new

Tags: ruby, mongodb, rubygems

I don't know what the deal is with this.  Everything works fine until i try to create a new MongoClient

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'mongo'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> include Mongo
=> Object
irb(main):004:0> client = MongoClient.new('127.0.0.1', 27017)
NameError: uninitialized constant MongoClient
        from (irb):4
        from :0
irb(main):005:0>
```

Comment: did you install mongo gem $ gem update --system
$ gem install mongo

Comment: What version of the gem are you using?

Comment: Yes. I installed mongo gem. I am using ruby 1.8.7

$gem which mongo
(checking gem mongo-1.5.2 for mongo)
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mongo-1.5.2/lib/mongo.rb

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using an older version (1.5.2) of the `mongo` gem instead of the most current one (1.8.0). That days the connection has been made by

```
conn = Mongo::Connection.new
```

Find out more in the [documentation of version 1.5.2](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/1.5.2/)

Comment: Thanks man. I was reading what must have been an old tutorial online.

Comment: Is there some other reasons for causing it? I came across with the same problem, but I changed the versions are all right:

tom@bktkowks04:~/Development/Learning-Ruby$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
=> false
irb(main):002:0> require 'mongo'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> include Mongo
=> Object
irb(main):004:0> client = MongoClient.new('MW-GAMP103240',60001)
NameError: uninitialized constant MongoClient
 from (irb):4
 from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'